# Nlog - database performance difference between target is offline and target not exists

Tags: database-connection, nlog

I was looking on internet about difference about database as target is offline, but exists and target not exists.

I have application that using NLog and I find out bug when my db target not exists then my performance is down from 100+ transactions per seconds to 1. But if I change case to database exists on target, but is down, then performance is good and it just stacking up things in queue.

Does anyone have experience with this? Why is so big difference between target offline and target not exist ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probable a timeout when writing. If every message that has to be written will give a timeout, this will slow down your application a lot.